# HtmlUnit to login (post form) to csrf enable website

Tags: post, authentication, csrf, htmlunit

I am posting a form using HTMLUnit webClient by putting the username and password but it could not logging me in. When i research then found out that they have enable csrf on post request so native web browser is required. Is there any way to login (post form) in csrf enable website using HTMLUnit or any other tool in Java or it is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit should behave exactly as browsers. Could you provide more detailed comparison (headers/response) between HtmlUnit and real browsers?